# Regex to match specific word and ignore specific word

Tags: java, regex

Currently I have a code like this

```
String[] departmentKeywords = trimmedArgs.split("\\s+");
```

I have a few departments, for example:

- Junior Managment
- Middle Management
- Senior Management
- Top Management

How can I make the regex such that whenever I type this:

```
junior middle
```

Will return people in Junior Management and Middle Management

```
management
```

Will return nothing, as I don't want it to print my whole management out.

```
junior top management
```

Will return people in Junior Management and Top Management

Thank you.

Edit 1:
Currently I have something like this:

```
public class FilterDepartmentCommandParser implements Parser<FilterDepartmentCommand> {

    public FilterDepartmentCommand parse(String args) throws ParseException {
        String trimmedArgs = args.trim();
        trimmedArgs = trimmedArgs.replaceAll("(?i)management", "");
        if (trimmedArgs.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ParseException(
                    String.format(MESSAGE_INVALID_COMMAND_FORMAT, FilterDepartmentCommand.MESSAGE_USAGE));
        }

        String[] departmentKeywords = trimmedArgs.split("\\s+");

        return new FilterDepartmentCommand(new DepartmentContainsKeywordsPredicate(Arrays.asList(departmentKeywords)));
    }
}
```

Currently it works for all the 3 examples I listed above. However, it does not work if I type the word "management" 1st followed by the keywords. For example:

```
management top junior
```

This should return me the people in Top Management and Junior Management.

However, it does not return me anything. Is there anyway I can improve this code?

Comment: I have a suspicion that regex may not be the best solution for this. You are putting your departments all together in a single string then splitting that string to get an array of strings of departments? Instead I would create an enum (or class) for departments and have certain attributes as a part of them.

Comment: @xtratic I currently have a class Person, which have fields such as Name, Department etc.. I'm currently creating a command which is able to filter out a list of people based on which departments they are in. However I'm facing a problem which is whenever I have the "management" word inside, it would list everyone out as all of my department contains the keyword "management".

Comment: I recommend you have a strict syntax for your command, only accept a list of 'junior','middle','senior', and 'top' return an error on any invalid inputs (including 'management'). Possibly convert those inputs to their associated enumerated types or values, then you can easily use those to select people within those departments.

Comment: The core idea is *parsing the input* and converting it to the specific departments that are being requested, then using those to select the people within those departments

Comment: @xtratic I have edited my code and it works for the 3 cases above. However, I'm now facing another problem, which is when management is typed 1st, it does not return me anything. Is there anyway I can improve from here? Thanks.

Comment: can you please provide all the methods you are using?

Comment: @steffen yes it helped me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
String[] departments = new String[] { "Junior Managment", "Middle Management", "Senior Management", "Top Management" };
String[] tests = new String[] { "management", "age", "junior", "mid", "op management", "uni middle", "junior middle management" };
for (String searchString : tests) {
    List<String> searchWords = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(searchString.split(" ")));
    searchWords.replaceAll(String::toLowerCase);
    searchWords.removeIf("management"::contains);
    Set<String> matches = new HashSet<>(departments.length);
    matches.addAll(Stream.of(departments)
            .filter(d -> searchWords.stream().anyMatch(d.toLowerCase()::contains))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));

    System.out.println(searchString + ": " + matches);
}
```

Output:

```
management: []
age: []
junior: [Junior Managment]
mid: [Middle Management]
op management: [Top Management]
uni middle: [Middle Management, Junior Managment]
junior middle management: [Middle Management, Junior Managment]
```